# undefined method 'document' for nil:NilClass while running Rails-tutorial with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org, minitest

I am following the `railstutorial by Michael Hartl`, and I don't understand the reason for failing tests in ***Chapter 5***. The book used the minitest framework but I decided to use RSpec. To do this, I deleted the test folder and included `rspec-rails` in my Gemfile then ran bundle install and `rails g rspec:install` to generate my spec folders. However, there are some tests that I feel convenient running with minitest syntax such as `assert_select` in static_pages_controller_spec.rb file. Here is how my spec file looks like:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe StaticPagesController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET #home" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :home
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get :home
      assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    end
  end

  describe "GET #help" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :help
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get :help
      assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    end
  end

  describe "GET #about" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :about
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get "about"
      assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the tests with RSpec, this is what I get as the failure error:

```
StaticPagesController GET #home should have the right title
 Failure/Error: assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `document' for nil:NilClass
# ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels)
in <top (required)>'
```

The same error message `(No Method error)` appears in each of the failing tests.

How can I fix it? Is there something I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error is that RSpec doesn't render views for controller specs by default. You can enable view rendering for a particular group of specs like this:

```
describe FooController, type: :controller do
  render_views

  # write your specs
end
```

or you can enable it globally by adding this somewhere in your RSpec config:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.render_views
end
```

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-6/docs/controller-specs/render-views for more information.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that assert_selected is a MiniTest construct whereas you are using RSpec.  You will need to use RSpec mechanisms for expecting view content https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-4/docs/view-specs/view-spec or add capybara to your Gemfile and use the capybara matchers: https://gist.github.com/them0nk/2166525

Comment: I use `assert_select` in RSpec view tests all the time with no issue.